# Model Binding CheckboxFor with ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, checkboxfor

My Class is

```
public partial class Team
    {
        public Team()
        {
            this.Trials = new HashSet<Trials>();               
        }

        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Trials> Trials { get; set; }
    }
```

and view is

```
@model Project.Classes.Team

 <td>
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trials.Count; i++ )
         {                
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).TrialID)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).isChk)  
             <br />               
         } 
</td>
```

When view is displayed it shows the Trials objects (3 Trials) in the model(Team) and displays on the form but when form is posted then in the controller I dont get any value for Trials it shows 0 Trials...I done it by Changing ICollection to IList in the class but ...Team Class is autogenerated by EF and when project re runs it forget the change so I want to do it with ICollection plz .....

Comment: Use this format in the loop: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Trials[i].Name)`

Comment: It says Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IColelction

Comment: You said you had changed it to `IList`, which is what you need for this to work. Alternatively you can create a custom `EditorTemplate` for `Trials` and use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Trials)` (no loop)

Comment: Thanks Stephen ..Sorry I am new to MVC and never used Editor Temp...Could you please advise me some good tutorial for Editor Template to get this working please......Thanks

Comment: I added an answer using an `EditorTemplate` (sorry, I misunderstood you comment about using `IList`)

Answer (score 1):

In you `View/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, add a new view named `Trials.cshtml` with the following code (create as a partial view)

```
@model YourAssembly.Trial
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isChk)
```

Then in your view, replace the loop with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Trials)`

```
@model Project.Classes.Team
....
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Trials)
```

`EditorFor` will correctly name collection items with the indexer for postback, for example it will generate

```
<input type="hidden" name="Trials[0].ID" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="Trials[1].ID" ...>
```

Note: Are you really wanting to display the whole collection within one table cell, or do you mean one `Trial` per row and the display name and checkbox in separate `td` elements? f so you can add the `tr` and `td` elements in the `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Thank you very much...Thanks...I can sort the dispaying issue....pleawse do advise me a turorial for Editor templates...I got it what you done here but want to know the whole theory ......Thanks again

Comment: Haven't come across a good tutorial, but [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) might give you a better understanding

Comment: Hi Stephen Sorry to bother you again...If I need to add another Editor Template for the same Trials class in which I want to display a multiple select dropdownlist what is the best approach.....I want to add multiple trials in a team using multiselect...

 @Html.ListBoxFor(model=> model.TrialID,
                  new SelectList(ViewBag.trials,"TrialID", "Name"),                   
                    new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Select Trials...", style = "width:500px;", tabindex = "4" }
                    )

Comment: You cant bind a multiple select to a single value. `TrialID` would need to be an array. You need to create a view model to represent what you want to display and edit. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519180/populating-listboxfor-with-viewmodel-and-passing-back-its-contents/25519304#25519304) may help. If not you need to ask another question

Comment: Thanks Stephen..I declared an int[] in Teams class and bind it with multiselect and got the seleted Trials...Thanks again